# Script error: jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js:2

Tags: jquery

When using Firefox to play games in Facebook, I get the following error message approximately every 5 minutes, even when I click the "don't ask me this again" box:

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js:2

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: wrong way here ...
check http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/ and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you can fix. Just firefox detects that some scripts take a lot of time to complete and guesses that the script may have stalled at some point and suggests you to stop the script to free up CPU and RAM. 
By the way it's likely that the script is working well and thats a firefox problem.
I know it's really annoying but you can't stop that functionality in firefox.